# Route VS RouteBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-routing

The question is quite straightforward:

> When we mention about implementing a custom Route Handler, when to
>   derive from `Route`, and when from `RouteBase` ?

Some possible scenarios:

1. SubdomainRouting
2. Include localization in URL
3. Custom GetVirtualPath for correct **URL** generation
4. Custom Constraints

Answer (score 0):

If you can do your redirection with what already exist from Route, select Route, if it's too complicated and need very special redirection code you can start from the Abstract RouteBase class.